Installing Ubuntu version 18.04 (i.e. prior to 20.04 and so on) throws errors
I am trying to install an older version of Ubuntu, namely the full desktop version of Ubuntu 18.04 in .iso form burnt to a plenty-large USB stick using Rufus 4.5.
The installer boots into GRUB just fine after which there is problem.

Here's what I see:
[6.357009] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to create kernel channel, -22
[7.096236] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: DRM: failed to create kernel channel, -22

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3) build-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of build-in commands.

(initramfs) stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /cow on /root failed: Invalid argument
overlay mount failed


The machine is a typical Intel x64 i9 I usually use for Windows 10 (and have done so for 11 in the past). Incidentally, it is equipped with a brace of Nvidia RTX2080Tis in SLI configuration. I mention this because of the reference to Nouveau in the error message.
I tried using the Asus Z390E mboard's onboard graphics adapter instead (which I believe to be Intel-based) via HDMI, but with the same result.

I am able to install later versions of Ubuntu without any such problem. Indeed, pretty much any other Linux distro's so called "Live DVD" or "Live USB" stick-type install has worked without a hitch.

Part of issue just may be 18.04 is just too old for newer hardware. Your install needs to be newer than hardware, so you have latest kernel & drivers to support that newer hardware.

This is an issue with ubuntu live usb versions before 19. It happens when you try to make a live usb with persistence in rufus. Set "persistent partition size" to 0 and it should work.


OK I tried this, but sadly I still have the same problem. Any other suggestions?
